# consul throwing an error

Tags: consul

Trying to run consul on my system.

Have followed link to download consul:

[consul and consul-template setup](https://sonnguyen.ws/install-consul-and-consul-template-in-ubuntu-14-04/)

```
consul agent -server -bootstrap-expect 1 \
    -data-dir /tmp/consul -node=agent-one \
    -bind=127.0.0.1:8500 \
    -client=0.0.0.0 \
    -config-dir /etc/consul.d \
    -ui-dir /opt/consul/
```

But getting an error:

```
WARNING: BootstrapExpect Mode is specified as 1; this is the same as Bootstrap mode.
==> WARNING: Bootstrap mode enabled! Do not enable unless necessary
==> Starting Consul agent...
==> Error starting agent: Failed to start Consul server: Failed to start lan serf: Failed to create memberlist: Failed to parse advertise address!
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like that the official Consul documentation is more up to date than the link that was posted in the question.

If one starts with the [Getting Started guide](https://www.consul.io/intro/getting-started/install.html), then one could start a consul agent in no time and the documentation also explains how to proceed.

```
user@localhost /tmp $ ./consul agent -dev
==> Starting Consul agent...
==> Consul agent running!
           Version: 'v1.0.6'
           Node ID: '777c5475-bc78-6e38-75a6-42038eef7cb8'
         Node name: 'localhost.localdomain'
        Datacenter: 'dc1' (Segment: '<all>')
            Server: true (Bootstrap: false)
       Client Addr: [127.0.0.1] (HTTP: 8500, HTTPS: -1, DNS: 8600)
      Cluster Addr: 127.0.0.1 (LAN: 8301, WAN: 8302)
           Encrypt: Gossip: false, TLS-Outgoing: false, TLS-Incoming: false

==> Log data will now stream in as it occurs:

    2018/04/09 21:33:04 [DEBUG] Using random ID "777c5475-bc78-6e38-75a6-42038eef7cb8" as node ID
```

Comment: thanks, it's working now, I have moved this to my /usr/bin folder and it's working fine, i don't know why the link I have added in question not working